# count variables with a certain condition

Tags: r

I am going to count if an event occurred and if it is occurred it had any consequence or not. Let's assume this is my data

```
#mydata

 a   b   c  d  consequence
 0   0   1  1    0
 1   0   1  1    1
 1   1   1  0    0
 0   0   0  1    0
```

So, for each variable I calculate how many times a variable occurred and how many times this variable caused a consequence:an example for "a"

```
  numberofa=length (subset(mydata, mydata$a==1))
  numberofaeffective= Length (subset(mydata, mydata$a==1 $ mydata$consequence=1))
```

How can I write a program to calculate these two metrics for each variable?

```
#expected output 

variable  count  count-with-effect
a        2          1
b        1          0
c        3          1
d        3          1
```

Comment: So, `consequence` is the expected output column?  Based on your code, it is subsetting the rows where 'a' is 1 and then again subsetting based on both column1.  I am not sure what is the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `sum` of logical vector

```
sum(dts$a==1)
#[1] 2
```

and

```
with(dts, sum(a==1 & consequence == 1))
#[1] 1
```

---

If we need it for each of the variables (i.e. 'a' to 'd')

```
colSums(dts[1:4] == 1)
# a b c d 
# 2 1 3 3
```

and for the second with 'consequence'

```
colSums(dts[1:4] == 1 & (dts[5] == 1)[row(dts[1:4])])
#a b c d 
#1 0 1 1
```

---

If we need it in a specific format, we can `gather` the dataset into 'long' format, then do the group by operation and `summarise` by `sum`ming the 'value' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gather(dts, variable, value, -consequence) %>% 
             group_by(variable) %>% 
             summarise(count = sum(value), count_with_effect = sum(value & consequence))
#  variable count count_with_effect
#     <chr> <int>             <int>
#1        a     2                 1
#2        b     1                 0
#3        c     3                 1
#4        d     3                 1
```